# Java file last modified returns 0

Tags: java, file, time, jcifs

I have the following code to check the last modification on a file saved on network drive.

```
private long determineLastEdit(ILoaderData file) {

    String localDir = "c:\\Software\\log\\"; 
    String localPDF = "empty28.pdf";
    String originDir = "smb:\\ProdName\\ShareName\\Temp\\username\\path\\to\\folder\\";
      //My company remote storage

    File localFile = new File(originDir + localPDF)
      //this does not work

    //File localFile = new File(localDir + localPDF)
      //this works as expected

    Date currentTime = new Date();
    long timeCurrent = currentTime.getTime();
    long timeFile = localFile.lastModified();
      //this returns 0 on remote, correct time on local

    boolean fileEx = localFile.isFile(); //returns false on remote, true on local
    boolean fileTp = localFile.isAbsolute(); //returns false on remote, true on local


    long difference = Math.abs(timeCurrent - timeFile);

    return difference;

}
```

The parameter given to constructor of a file is following:

```
smb:\\\ProdName\\\ShareName\\\Temp\\\username\\\path\\\to\\\folder\\\empty28.pdf
```

However, the lastModified() method returns 0 for some reason, what am I doing wrong? The file has no lock of any kind, it is regular (altough empty PDF).

**EDIT1:** I tested the method on local file, the path was:

```
c:\\\Software\\\log\\\empty28.pdf
```

And the value returned was correct, my suspicion was that method was not allowed to execute on a given file since it's on network drive. However, this check happens on one thread that is already authorized. No clue where the error is.

**EDIT2:** I updated code to provide better examples. Right now, it seems the problem is with reading file from network drive

**EDIT3** I Tried using different method. Imported:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
```

and added code:

```
Path path = Paths.get(localDir + localPDF);
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
```

with same result, again, local drive works and remote is not working.

Comment: `boolean fileEx = localFile.isFile(); //returns false`?  That "returns false" seems important...

Comment: It does, to me it looks like it doesnt even register the file, however that makes little to no sense to me. Will test on local file.

Comment: if it returns 0, that means the file doesn't exist.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()

Comment: I tested the implementation with local file and it worked, updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as this (note: I included a date format):

```
String localPDF = "empty28.pdf";
String originDir = "\\\\smb\\ProdName\\ShareName\\Temp\\username\\path\\to\\file\\";

File file = new File(originDir + localPDF);   
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println(sdf.format(file.lastModified()));
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works, however not for file saved on network shared drive.

Comment: @LoneWanderer It does work for the network; maybe try editing your path? - I've slightly updated my answer (note the four slashes)

Comment: I bring news! I tried this with both methods. With original implementation, is still doesnt work, however when I check if the path is absolute, it returns `true` . This means that the path is correct, however it still doesnt recognize the file. When I used second implementation (hence EDIT 3) it i get and exception `the network path was not found` with this path \\smb\ProdName\ShareName\Temp\username\path\to\file\empty28.pdf

Comment: Not sure my man, I literally just created that exact path (with changing smb to one already on my system) and it executes as expected; if you paste the path into the run box (assuming Windows), does it open the folder? (\\smb\ProdName\ShareName\Temp\username\path\to\file\). If so, did you add the extra slashes, i.e. double each one - IDEs may do this automatically.

Comment: Interestingly, no, it does not. I would assume thats my problem. I tried to use my mapped drive (since I have this share mapped to Z:) and it worked like a charm, however this is likely due to the fact, that windows treats it as logical drive. Is there a way to get the network address of that particular location?

Comment: With some more testing, it started to work, the trick was in the path. It needed to be `\\\\ProdName\\ShareName\\Temp\\username\\path\\to\\file\\empty28.pdf` So removing the protocol name helped.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) the method lastModified:

> Returns a long value representing the time the file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970), or 0L if the file does not exist or if an I/O error occurs.

So, check out your URL you passes to the File's constructor.